# Meaning of '' in a way''

Tags: phrase-meaning

> ''Nothing in this complexity stands in the way of claiming that statistical mechanics describes the world ***in a way*** that explains why thermodynamics works and works as well as it does.''
>
> Luckily, Ford is more enthusiastic: "Nick performs in a way that seems effortless, subtle and honest.

In these sentences Does '' in a way '' has the same meaning as '' in such a way '' ? What does it mean ? As far as I know ''in such a way'' is used like '' so that'' but I think in these sentences ''in a way '' is not the same as ''in such a way''.

Comment: ***in a way** that [does something] = **in such a way as to** [do something]*. Note that *in principle* we could introduce a full stop after *...statistical mechanics describes the world.* Then the newly-created sentence that follows would mean something like *That [= "the preceding sentence"] **loosely** explains why thermodynamics works* (it's a ***kind*** of explanation).

Comment: The **way** of describing the world (used in statistical mechanics as its method) **explains** (is capable of it) why thermodynamics works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, "in such a way" would not be possible here.

The word *that* is a relative pronoun in the example you gave. It's followed by a clause of which "way" is the implied subject. It's the same use of *that* that you would find in a sentence like "I want a computer *that* works well in extreme temperatures."

Here is an example of *in such a way that*:

> As he was pulling the battery cover off, he damaged it in such a way that nobody could get it back on again afterwards.

Here the word *that* is a conjunction. It is followed by a clause with its own subject. What follows is a consequence of the particular way in which he damaged the battery cover.

Here are a few more examples of *such ... that*:

> *He struck the coconut with such force that it shattered into fifteen pieces.*
>
> *He had such great success in business that he was able to retire at forty.*
>
> *They had such a good time together that she insisted they meet again the next evening.* (Note: this is the subjunctive form of "meet." In British English, "met" or "should meet" would probably be more likely.)